# Can i configure gradle to forbid a specific set of dependencies?

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I have a situation where in my project I have 3 type of modules
'

1. Application modules
2. Service modules
3. Infrastructure modules

The allowed dependencies would be

1. Application modules can depend on Service modules and/or Infrastructure ones
2. Service modules can depend on infrastructure modules

This means that, for example, it is not allowed to have an Infrastructure module to depend on a Service one.

Surely this can be easily controlled by simply not adding those dependencies in gradle, however I wonder if there is a way to explicitly forbid such a thing (and sure, I could simply add a comment in gradle), I am looking not only to fail the build if such dependency exists, but also to provide a message explaining why.

So the question is

1. Does this make sense?
2. Can this be achieved with some gradle plugin?

Just for the record, I have searched this and so far what I found was related to transitive dependency management.

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to explicitly forbid it? If it would break something, can't you add a test for that instead?

Comment: This involvesa project where many people work, some modules are not allowed, by architecture, to access other modules, and i just want to make triple sure that if that happens by a mistake, the developer get a message stating the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like if you blacklist the tomcat starter in spring boot. This is done natively, so no need for an extra plugin.

```
dependencies {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
          if (details.requested.group == 'org.springframework.boot' && details.requested.name == 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat') {
            logger.error "tomcat found"
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't use tomcat here!")
          }
        }
    }
}
```